# Foreign key constraint error in Laravel, Integrity constraint violation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to add a foreign key to the user table, and it shows me the error below. This is the news column I need to add to the user table.

```
Schema::table('file_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
});
```

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
> update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`bakr`.`#sql-3e24_445`, CONSTRAINT `file_categories_user_id_foreign`
> FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
> (SQL: alter table `file_categories` add constraint
> `file_categories_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references
> `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: It's likely your `file_categories` table references some user_ids that don't have a corresponding record in the users table.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your foreign key definition has nullable property.

```html
 $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
```

This might be occurring because SQL expects the foreign id column to have data, but since you didn't mention any default data, the field can be nullable.